# what does this function is actually doing in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

this is the function .   Here app is a express variable
views folder contain the list of ejs files .  i know the meaning  of second argument but on a what it is explaining is not clear

Comment: You're just setting the `views` application setting - http://expressjs.com/api.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For rendering, you might used render method like this

```
 res.render('login', { "title" : "login" } );
```

Here login is template name, how express identify where to take login template ?

```
 app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

so this line tells express to take templates from the views directory inside current directory.

Answer (score -1):

Using [`app.set`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.set) sets a value that can later be retrieved with `app.get`.
In this case `views` is part of the built in [application settings](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.settings.table), with the description

> A directory or an array of directories for the application's views.
>   If
>   an array, the views are looked up in the order they occur in the
>   array.

[`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) is the name of the directory that the currently executing script resides in, so you're setting it to that directory plus `/views`.

In other words, you've jost told Express that your views reside in a given folder.